# angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.23 (2016-12-15) NOT on npm

Tags: angular-cli

Although angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.23 (2016-12-15) is released, I cannot install it from npm - the current npm version is  angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.22-1. Is this an oversight? Could we correct it please?

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues with that release, there will be another release this coming week.

> NOTE:
>   This is not really a good question for this site, in the future please post questions of this nature in the [GitHub project](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) as an issue.